# can a c vector store more than one data type?

Tags: c++, function, class

I'd like to write a function that will return 4 members of a class. They are 3 ints and char, and I'd like to store them all in one vector and return it from a function call. Can I do that?

Comment: To do *exactly* what you ask, you would use an union of int and char, and return a vector of that union. However, this is really *not* the way to do it. You should show what you have tried, and what the data actually is.

Answer (score 3):

You either need an [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) if you want to preserve the types and if the result length is constant, or just cast all members to some common supertype and store them in a container.

Answer (score 2):

You need a class:

```
struct S
{
    int a, b, c;
    char letter;
};

int main()
{
    S s;
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, question was not about returning a vector of structs with 4 members, it was about returning a vector of length four, with the 4 values in the vector (which does not make much sense, of course...).

Comment: @hyde Yeah, but it wouldn't work out that way. Whatever the OP meant, I think this is what he should be using.

Comment: I think the sensible interpretation of the question is, just return the struct, not a vector. But returning a vector of unions would certainly work, if OP really wants to do it that way.